# How can i solve refresh problem in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, server

I am a very beginner at node js programming language. I just want to asked that why   i have to run on command line after each change in js file.
for example:

i changed form this

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.write("The date and time are currently displaying");
    res.end('Hello World!');
}).listen(9001);
```

to

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.write("The date");
    res.end('Hello World!');
}).listen(9001);
```

and when i refresh it did not change in browser.

And when i run it through cmd and then refresh the browser it changed.
Kindly tell me what should i do to instant change in browser whenever i 
change in js file.And why it does't changed.

Comment: It doesn't change because when you type `node server.js`, node loads the file into memory and runs it. Changing the file on the hard drive afterwards does nothing. If you've previously used PHP for instance, refreshing the browser is enough because a PHP script is a one-time deal that is executed by php every time you refresh the browser. With node though you are writing the actual server, not just instructions for it. The mechanism is different. Changing the node source is like changing php.ini (which does require restarting the server)

Comment: If you use a web framework like express though, you'll be writing pug or ejs templates which contain server-side code. Changing these and refreshing the browser does work like you expect it to, and doesn't require restarting the server.

Answer (score 3):

You might be running your node server using

**`node filename.js`**

If you want to just restart the server after every change made, you should use the **nodemon** package of npm.

Do:

Step1: Install nodemon using

```
(sudo) npm install -g nodemon
```

Step 2: After installation, just go to project folder and run

```
nodemon
```

Now on any change made to the node file, the node server will restart automatically with the latest changes.

Comment: I do these step but it is not working.I mean not refreshing.

Comment: You just observe in your terminal whether your server is restarting or not? If it is restarting, you just need to refresh your browser manually.